# How to ask user for permission to publish in his news feed?

Tags: facebook

This is what I have so far

```
<input type="submit" />
<fb:prompt-permission perms="publish_stream">Click Here</fb:prompt-permission>
```

I want to prompt the user by showing him a dialog box to allow my application to publish in his news feed when he clicks the submit button.

Comment: so what is the question? fb:prompt-permission shows extended permission dialog, yes. (and submit is ambiguous here)

Comment: I want the fb:prompt-permission action to be triggered when I click the submit button in my application.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is to is convert over to using the Facebook Javascript API.  The normal workflow is to ask the user to login prior to having them fill out a form that get's published to his wall. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ for more information.